# Split string in characters turns & into &amp;

Tags: jquery, string, split

I am splitting a string by each character and wrapping them in a span. I'm using a modified version of the script from splt.js. When the string contains special characters such as '&' it will return
`<span>&</span><span>a</span><span>m</span><span>p</span><span>;</span>` instead of just &. Is there a way to solve that? This is what the code looks like:

````
function splt({ target: q = ".splt", reveal: o = !1 }) {
    let r = [],
        b = document.querySelectorAll(q);
    for (let a = 0; a < b.length; a++) {
        b[a].setAttribute("id", "i" + [a + 1]), r.push(b[a].innerHTML);
        let l = b[a].innerHTML.split(" ");
        for (let g = 0; g < l.length; g++) {
            let m = document.createElement("span");
            l[g] += " ";
            let h = l[g].split("");
            for (let c = 0; c < h.length; c++) {
                let d = document.createElement("span");
                if ((m.appendChild(d), d.setAttribute("id", "c" + [c + 1]), " " == h[c] ? d.classList.add("whtSpc") : d.classList.add("char"), !0 == o)) {
                    let i = document.createElement("span");
                    (i.innerHTML = h[c]), d.appendChild(i), i.setAttribute("id", "r"), i.classList.add("reveal");
                } else d.innerHTML = h[c];
            }
            (m.style.display = "inline-block"), b[a].appendChild(m);
        }
        b[a].removeChild(b[a].childNodes[0]);
    }
    let j = document.querySelectorAll(".char");
    for (let e = 0; e < j.length; e++) (j[e].style.display = "inline-block"), (j[e].style.overflow = "hidden"), (j[e].style.verticalAlign = "top");
    let p = document.querySelectorAll(".whtSpc");
    for (let n = 0; n < p.length; n++) p[n].style["white-space"] = "pre";
    if (!0 == o) {
        let k = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
        for (let f = 0; f < k.length; f++) (k[f].style.display = "inherit"), (k[f].style.overflow = "inherit"), (k[f].style.verticalAlign = "inherit");
    }
    splt.revert = () => {
        for (let a = 0; a < b.length; a++) b[a].removeAttribute("id"), (b[a].innerHTML = r[a]);
    };
}
splt({ target: ".splt", reveal: !1 });
```
````

Comment: The problem is that your string splitting is too naive and doesn't handle HTML entites like `&amp;` which gets replaced by a literal `&` in the displayed HTML. There are many other examples that your code will need to be aware of - See [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for more info

Comment: yeah, of course. Is there a way you could ignore those or something?

Answer (score 0):

oh; I might have solved it by replacing this line:

```
let l = b[a].innerHTML.split(" ");
```

with this:

```
let l = b[a].innerText.split(" ");
```

is that going to work or are there other potential problems by doing so?